# Customized Material Tailwind Themes

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I wonder if how can I customize the background color and text color from this website https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/navbar

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Navbar,
  Collapse,
  Typography,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Menu,
  MenuHandler,
  MenuList,
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import {
  ChevronDownIcon,
  Bars3Icon,
  XMarkIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import {
  Bars4Icon,
  GlobeAmericasIcon,
  NewspaperIcon,
  PhoneIcon,
  RectangleGroupIcon,
  SquaresPlusIcon,
  SunIcon,
  TagIcon,
  UserGroupIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
 
const navListMenuItems = [
  {
    title: "Products",
    description: "Find the perfect solution for your needs.",
    icon: SquaresPlusIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "About Us",
    description: "Meet and learn about our dedication",
    icon: UserGroupIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "Blog",
    description: "Find the perfect solution for your needs.",
    icon: Bars4Icon,
  },
  {
    title: "Services",
    description: "Learn how we can help you achieve your goals.",
    icon: SunIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "Support",
    description: "Reach out to us for assistance or inquiries",
    icon: GlobeAmericasIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "Contact",
    description: "Find the perfect solution for your needs.",
    icon: PhoneIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "News",
    description: "Read insightful articles, tips, and expert opinions.",
    icon: NewspaperIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "Products",
    description: "Find the perfect solution for your needs.",
    icon: RectangleGroupIcon,
  },
  {
    title: "Special Offers",
    description: "Explore limited-time deals and bundles",
    icon: TagIcon,
  },
];
 
function NavListMenu() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const renderItems = navListMenuItems.map(
    ({ icon, title, description }, key) => (
      <a href="#" key={key}>
        <MenuItem className="flex items-center gap-3 rounded-lg">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg !bg-blue-gray-50 p-2 ">
            {" "}
            {React.createElement(icon, {
              strokeWidth: 2,
              className: "h-6 text-gray-900 w-6",
            })}
          </div>
          <div>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color="blue-gray"
              className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold"
            >
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="paragraph"
              className="text-xs !font-medium text-blue-gray-500"
            >
              {description}
            </Typography>
          </div>
        </MenuItem>
      </a>
    ),
  );
 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu
        open={isMenuOpen}
        handler={setIsMenuOpen}
        offset={{ mainAxis: 20 }}
        placement="bottom"
        allowHover={true}
      >
        <MenuHandler>
          <Typography as="div" variant="small" className="font-medium">
            <ListItem
              className="flex items-center gap-2 py-2 pr-4 font-medium text-gray-900"
              selected={isMenuOpen || isMobileMenuOpen}
              onClick={() => setIsMobileMenuOpen((cur) => !cur)}
            >
              Resources
              <ChevronDownIcon
                strokeWidth={2.5}
                className={`hidden h-3 w-3 transition-transform lg:block ${
                  isMenuOpen ? "rotate-180" : ""
                }`}
              />
              <ChevronDownIcon
                strokeWidth={2.5}
                className={`block h-3 w-3 transition-transform lg:hidden ${
                  isMobileMenuOpen ? "rotate-180" : ""
                }`}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </Typography>
        </MenuHandler>
        <MenuList className="hidden max-w-screen-xl rounded-xl lg:block">
          <ul className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-y-2 outline-none outline-0">
            {renderItems}
          </ul>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
      <div className="block lg:hidden">
        <Collapse open={isMobileMenuOpen}>{renderItems}</Collapse>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
 
function NavList() {
  return (
    <List className="mt-4 mb-6 p-0 lg:mt-0 lg:mb-0 lg:flex-row lg:p-1">
      <Typography
        as="a"
        href="#"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="font-medium"
      >
        <ListItem className="flex items-center gap-2 py-2 pr-4">Home</ListItem>
      </Typography>
      <NavListMenu />
      <Typography
        as="a"
        href="#"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="font-medium"
      >
        <ListItem className="flex items-center gap-2 py-2 pr-4">
          Contact Us
        </ListItem>
      </Typography>
    </List>
  );
}
 
export function NavbarWithMegaMenu() {
  const [openNav, setOpenNav] = React.useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "resize",
      () => window.innerWidth >= 960 && setOpenNav(false),
    );
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <Navbar className="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-2">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-blue-gray-900">
        <Typography
          as="a"
          href="#"
          variant="h6"
          className="mr-4 cursor-pointer py-1.5 lg:ml-2"
        >
          Material Tailwind
        </Typography>
        <div className="hidden lg:block">
          <NavList />
        </div>
        <div className="hidden gap-2 lg:flex">
          <Button variant="text" size="sm" color="blue-gray">
            Log In
          </Button>
          <Button variant="gradient" size="sm">
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </div>
        <IconButton
          variant="text"
          color="blue-gray"
          className="lg:hidden"
          onClick={() => setOpenNav(!openNav)}
        >
          {openNav ? (
            <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" strokeWidth={2} />
          ) : (
            <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" strokeWidth={2} />
          )}
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      <Collapse open={openNav}>
        <NavList />
        <div className="flex w-full flex-nowrap items-center gap-2 lg:hidden">
          <Button variant="outlined" size="sm" color="blue-gray" fullWidth>
            Log In
          </Button>
          <Button variant="gradient" size="sm" fullWidth>
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

I wanted to change the background color, the active, focus, visited and etc. styling of the said frameworks. Can you give me a piece of advice how to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking the [theming guide on the Material Tailwind website](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/theming):

> Customize @material-tailwind/react with your own theme. You can change the base styles like the colors, typography, box-shadows and breakpoints as well as the components style.
>
> @material-tailwind/react come's with a `ThemeProvider` component that you can use to set your own theme or use the default theme provided by @material-tailwind/react.
>
> ## Theme Provider
>
> The `ThemeProvider` component give you the ability to use and customize the default theme or set your own theme for @material-tailwind/react.
>
> You need to wrap your component or entire application with the `ThemeProvider` component to use the theme.
>
> ```
> import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";
>
> export default function App() {
>   const customTheme = { ... }
>
>   return <ThemeProvider value={customTheme}>...</ThemeProvider>;
> }
> ```
>
> […]
>
> ## Theme Object Structure
>
> The theme object is a plain object that contains all of the components styles object. All of the components styles are available in the theme object and these styles object has a unique format for different use cases.
>
> ```js
> const theme = {
>   component: {
>     defaultProps: { ... },
>     valid: { ... },
>     styles: { ... }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> | Key | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `theme` | It's the main theme object that should be passed as value for the `ThemeProvider`. |
> | `component` | It's the name of component that you want to customize. e.g button. |
> | `defaultProps` | Is used to change the default props value for components. |
> | `valid` | Is used to change the valid values for components props validation. |
> | `styles` | Is used to change the styles of a component. |
>
> To know more about how to customize the component theme object for a specific component please check the component documentation page.

So, for `Navbar` as an example, we can [consult its documentation page](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/navbar#navbar-theme-customization) to customize its theming to how you'd like:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";

export default function App() {
  const customTheme = {
    navbar: {
      variants: {
        filled: {
          white: {
            background: '…',
            color: '…',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return <ThemeProvider value={customTheme}>…</ThemeProvider>;
}
```

Comment: So this should be jsx file right?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your project, but "you need to wrap your component or entire application with the `ThemeProvider` component to use the theme."

Comment: Is it advises able to override the design of tailwind tru custom css? Is there any conflict or int?

Comment: You could consider [reading just a tiny bit further in the linked page of the documentation](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/theming#class-name).